# How to get just the root directory (and another subdirectory) when doing git-archive

Tags: git

I want to use git-archive to grab a subset of a repository. e.g suppose this repo layout

```
foo.js 
blah.sh
subdir/
   whatever.js
   morestuff.js
subdir2_which_contains_A_LOT_of_stuff/
   whatever.js
   morestuff.js
```

I know I can grab subdir with `git archive -o ../subarchive.zip HEAD:subdir` but how can I grab the root and subdir, without `subdir2_which_contains_A_LOT_of_stuff`

It would be ok to explicitly blacklist `subdir2_which_contains_A_LOT_of_stuff` somehow

edit: I don't think my initial premise on this question was correct, so I don't think the answers are valid :/ (in particular the "I know I can grab subdir with" bit is a misconception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `git archive` man page, we can see:

```
--worktree-attributes
  Look for attributes in .gitattributes files in the working tree as well (see the section called “ATTRIBUTES”).
```

and

```
ATTRIBUTES
export-ignore
  Files and directories with the attribute export-ignore won’t be added to archive files. See gitattributes(5) for details.

export-subst
  If the attribute export-subst is set for a file then Git will expand several placeholders when adding this file to an archive. See gitattributes(5) for details.
```

… so you may define a dedicated **.gitattributes** file that would suit your needs.

Alternatively, we're also been told that :

```
<extra>
   This can be any options that the archiver backend understands. See next section.
```

So, for instance, if we're winding up a tarball and the back end command is **tar**, we can use **--exclude** (which is part of tar, not git) to achieve the same, which may easier than defining a whole Git policy.